# Send filter from Scorecard to Analytic Grid

Tags: filter, performancepoint, dashboard-designer-2013

1. The figure has an Analytic Grid at the bottom.
2. It has a measure called [Application Count].
3. And it has a dimension named [Day Bucket].
4. At the top is scorecard. It has several calculated measures.
5. [Too Early] is the sum of [Application Count] for first [Day Buckets] as shown in green, viz: [0 - 5 Days] to [21 - 25 Days].
6. [On time] is the sum of [Application Count] for [Day Buckets] from [26 - 30 Days] to [41 - 45 Days].
7. Like wise, [Late] and [Unacceptable] are two other calculated members.
8. I am required to send a filter from a cell or column in Scorecard (at top) to the Analytic Grid (at the bottom).
9. When I click a green cell in [Too Early] it should show only the green cells in Anatlyic Grid and when I click a yello cell in [On time] it should show only the yellow cells in Analytic Grid.
10. Please enlighten me how to pass the filter parameters from Scorecard to Grid in my scenario.

Thanks in Advance,
Merin

[image: Send filter from Scorecard to Analytic Grid]